# Should I use Table-per-hierarchy?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

**UPDATED with image at the bottom**

I have three entities - Company, Project, Employee.

Company has one or more CompanyManagers. 
Project has exactly one ProjectManager. 
Employee has exactly one EmployeeManager

I want to create a database design and then create EF Code First Model for this.

Should I create separate tables for storing CompanyManagers, ProjectManagers and EmployeeManagers

Or

Should I create a single table that will store the various managers? Such a table could look like this:
ManagerID

EntityType (Company, Project, Employee)

EntityID (CompanyID, ProjectID, EmployeeID)

**UPDATED**
Here is the design so far:

[image]

Comment: Which strategy to use depends on more factors that the detail you supply, a.o. the number of fields all types have in common. An excellent series of posts that will help you in this decision starts [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know - that depends on your application requirements. Anyway even with TPH you will still have separate `CompanyID`, `ProjectID`, `EmployeeID` columns because columns mapped to specific properties of derived type cannot be reused and you cannot build conditional relation on column.

Comment: could I use EntityType or a combination of EntityType and EntityID as the discriminator column for this table and the entity.  I would not map the table with any other table.  This table will just be used to store the various managers.  If this is not recommended, could you please provide other suggestions.  I have updated the question with a diagram of the design so far.  I now need to store the various managers.  Appreciate your time on this.